# Using asp.net ajax method to stop the page from refreshing after a buttonclick in VS2012

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, visual-studio-2012

Using VS2012, I have a button that gets clicked to return some info to a textbox on the screen. I also have a label, label3, that is set to the following

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Label3.Text = ("THE FIRST RUN RECORDED AT" + DateTime.Now.ToString(" hh:mm:ss tt"));

    }
```

Now naturally every time I press the button to return my information in the other part of the c#/web form it refreshes the `hh:mm:ss` to the current time.

My question is - Where I can call my function to stop my label from refreshing when the button is clicked?

The button calls this

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        WebService1 ws1 = new WebService1();
        Label2.Text = ws1.codes(TextBox1.Text);
    }
```

It just returns a string dependent on input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place Label3 out of UpdatePanel and other controls inside UpdatePanel.
In aspx :

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server"></asp:Label>
<br />
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<br />
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click2" Text="OK" />
        <br />
        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server"></asp:Label>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: Where abouts is UpdatePanel... I'm still getting to know my way around Visual Studio

Comment: Well, i found it in the toolbox -> ajax extensions, seems I have to add it to the default.aspx page?

Comment: Yeah.. got it, I just added it on the design page and put everything but label3 in it, thanks.